# Add local files to Node-RED on server

Tags: node-red

to make my job easier I need to upload local files from my pc to Node in Node-RED located on server. For now I can only use files that are already on the server `/home/pi/whatever.txt`. Is there a way to just kinda drag and drop (or just insert local path) local file that will be loaded in node?

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail about what you are trying to do. How will the files be consumed?

Comment: to custom made node I'm providing .csv file, then content of this file will be saved as variable. So file needs to be loaded only once every deploy.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to remember that none of tbe flow actually executes in the browser, it all runs on the backend, so there is no where to drag/drop a file to.

What you can do is create a HTTP endpoint to which you can POST the file using the `http-in` & `http-response` nodes. Both these nodes are in the core set.

You need to make sure that the message that comes out of the `http-in` node makes it all the way to the `http-response` for the connection to be completed and closed properly.

Something like the following should work.

http-in -> csv -> custom node -> http-response

If you set the `http-in` node to POST mode and set the the path to `/csv`

You can post the file using something like curl from the remote machine with something like

```
curl -X POST http://example.com/csv --data "@/path/to/file.csv"
```

You may need to play around with the mime type.